# .net core switching appsettings configuration based on domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

How do I get the current domain in the *Startup.cs* `ConfigureServices`? Basically I need to change some settings depending on the domain. All settings are stored in *appsettings.json*

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Brands": [
    {
      "Name": "Brand A",
      "Domain": "branda.com",
      "Uri": [ "promo1", "promo2" ],
      "AssetsDir": "assets/branda"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Brand B",
      "Domain": "brandb.com",
      "Uri": [ "promo1", "promo2" ],
      "AssetsDir": "assets/brandb"
    }
  ]
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    var brands = Configuration.GetSection("Brands")
        .GetChildren()
        .ToList();

    // look up brands based on the current domain
    // load settings into config


    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that. The domain is a per request value, and the startup will run once when the application loads. If you're application handles only one domain per deployment then you should make your configuration unique to the deployment.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth thanks for your quick response. Ok, I'll probably get all the config settings and still store it as a config option. Then in my controller, i'll do the switching. Does this make sense? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments - I recommend you to load all the settings and using action filters to identify the current domain and load the required settings.

Here is some pseudo-code to identify domain.

```
public class TenantAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        var fullAddress = actionExecutingContext.HttpContext?.Request?
            .Headers?["Host"].ToString()?.Split('.');
        if (fullAddress.Length < 2)
        {
            actionExecutingContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(404);
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);
        }
        else
        {
            var subdomain = fullAddress[0];
            //We got the subdomain value, next verify it from database and
            //inject the information to RouteContext
        }
    }
}
```

This link also might help you - https://dotnetthoughts.net/building-multi-tenant-web-apps-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I will try this as well